# Reference Request - Developement of Geometry

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I am looking for a reference that explains the developement of geometry that includes the developement from around the mid nineteenth century to modern geometry. By *explain*, I mean that it gives reasons to *why* one would introduce or alter given ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book [Geometry from a differentiable viewpoint](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009XBO9L8) might fit what you are asking for, although the focus is on the development of differential geometry, as you might guess from the title.